# How to obtain Chrome stable version .deb or zip or tarball for Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, terminal

I am in a network where Google is blocked. I needed to install Google Chrome. Hence I cannot go to Chrome download page, it is restricted. Neither can I use

```
apt-get install google-chrome-stable.
```

It returns error.

Since I don't have access to Google urls, I tried the below command and tried to install

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Doesn't work. Hence I need a URL or third party repository which has chrome.deb files. Or any other alternative to download chrome. No I do not have USB port to download and copy. It's on a virtual machine.

Comment: Would Chromium be OK? That is in the Ubuntu repo.

Comment: yes chromium will also do.

Comment: [Plenty of download links here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=chromium+download), usual caveats about security apply, of course. [And try this](https://github.com/scheib/chromium-latest-linux), linked from an official Chromium source.

Comment: Halfer. Thank you. what i did was, since my network did not allow to access google. I redirected the request through a  proxy network. i.e. by adding proxy paths in /etc/environment and for apt installs i added a file called 95proxies in the apt directory. this resolved my case.

Comment: Great! Would you add that as an answer? If that is a free proxy I would normally worry about that from a security perspective, but I believe apt updates are public-key signed, so a rogue download would be rejected by your system.

Comment: No that was not a free proxy. there was a provision for using proxy in our network. Its some box in the network. I don't have any idea of networking. IT person gave the network IP and I used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since our network does not allow to access Google redirected the request through a proxy network. i.e. by adding proxy paths in `/etc/environment` and for apt installs add a file called `95proxies` in the `apt` directory.

Then use `apt-get install google-chrome-stable`.

Comment: Ah, that requires the use of a proxy server, [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175172/how-do-i-configure-proxies-without-gui). To be more complete, your answer could indicate what the `95proxies` file should contain, perhaps? If it is officially documented somewhere though, you could add a link to that.

Comment: yes. This is useful in a office network which has a proxy server to forward requests to external internet.